# Time-of-day triggers

Tags: timers

How can I set timers in Emacs to trigger at certain times of day? [Midnight mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MidnightMode) adds hooks for a single "midnight" time, but I would like to create separate hooks for multiple clock times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`run-at-time`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html#index-run_002dat_002dtime-5124) to run some code at a specific time.

For example, to message "go home" every day at 5 pm:

```
(setq go-home-timer
      (run-at-time "5:00pm"
                   (* 24 60 60)
                   (lambda ()
                     (message "go home!"))))
```

You can stop it with:

```
(cancel-timer go-home-timer)
```

You can create a [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) and set it up to run at 5pm every day:

```
(defun end-of-work-hook nil
  "The hook run at the end of the day")

(setq go-home-timer
      (run-at-time "5:00pm"
                   (* 24 60 60)
                   (lambda () (run-hooks 'end-of-work-hook))))
```

Then you add things to that hook as normal:

```
(add-hook 'end-of-work-hook
          (lambda ()
            (message "go home!")))
```